# How to static assert a condition on a string literal inside of a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, static-assert

In the following example `main` can `static_assert` if a string literal starts with `'v'`, but `verify` can not.

Why is it happening? Is there a way to allow `verify` to `static_assert` conditions on characters in a string literal?

```
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr char get_first(const char (&str)[N])
{
    static_assert(N>1, "must be > 1");
    return str[0];
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr void verify(const char (&str)[N])
{
    static_assert(str[0] == 'v', "must start from v");   
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(get_first("value") == 'v', "first must be 'v'"); // succeeds
    verify("value"); // fails to compile
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr void verify(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 6]':
main.cpp:19:15:   required from here
main.cpp:13:9: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
         static_assert(str[0] == 'v', "must start from v");
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:9: error: 'str' is not a constant expression
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c58e320a1bae0d7).

Comment: If you want a string parameter you can compile-time assert on, I suggest Hana.

Answer (score 3):

I have another workaround for you. This will not use `static_assert` but is guaranteed to enforce the condition on compile time.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<bool b>
using enforce = std::bool_constant<b>;

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr int verify(const char (&str)[N])
{
    if(get_first(str) != 'v') {
        throw "must start from v";
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    using assertion = enforce<verify("value")>; // compiles
    using assertion = enforce<verify("fail")>; // fails to compile
    // or use it like
    constexpr auto assertion0 = verify("value"); // compiles
}
```

This uses that throwing is not valid in a constexpr context. The error you'll receive will look somethign like this:

```
26 : <source>:26:31: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    using assertion = enforce<verify("fail")>; // fails to compile
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
15 : <source>:15:9: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
        throw "must start from v";
        ^
26 : <source>:26:31: note: in call to 'verify("fail")'
    using assertion = enforce<verify("fail")>; // fails to compile
```

We can enforce constexpr evaluation of `verify` by using it as a template argument. That's also the reason for declaring a non-void return type.

Comment: another way is to store the value of `verify()` in a `constexpr` value; by example: `constexpr int vr0 = verify("value"); constexpr int vr1 = verify("fail");`; no need for `enforce`, in that case

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you can wrap the value in a constexpr lambda ([online demo](https://godbolt.org/g/oamBfr)). The call looks like

```
verify([=] { return "value"; });
```

and to unwrap you can

```
template <class StringWrapper>
constexpr void verify(StringWrapper str_w)
{
    constexpr auto str = str_w();
    static_assert(str[0] == 'v', "must start from v");   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `verify()`

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr void verify(const char (&str)[N])
{
    static_assert(str[0] == 'v', "must start from v");   
}
```

can be called compile-time **and** run-time.

So the error, because can perform a `static_assert()`, over `str`, when called compile-time but can't when called runtime (when the first char of `str` isn't known compile-time).

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask for a compile-time check over a string literal.

The following is a silly example and I suppose isn't really useful, but I hope can be of inspiration

```
template <char const * const str>
constexpr bool startWithUpperLetter ()
 { 
   static_assert( str[0] != 'v', "no start with \'v\', please" );

   return (str[0] >= 'A') && (str[0] <= 'Z');
 }

constexpr char const str1[] { "ABC" };
constexpr char const str2[] { "abc" };
constexpr char const str3[] { "vwx" };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( startWithUpperLetter<str1>() == true, "!" );
   static_assert( startWithUpperLetter<str2>() == false, "!" );
   // static_assert( startWithUpperLetter<str3>() == false, "!" ); // error
 }
```

Comment: Is there any language rule that makes the function or function call more run-time than we think or less compile-time than we think?

Comment: @NickyC - not sure to understand your question but... without `constexpr`, a function is (ideally) run-time only; with `constexpr` is run-time **and** compile-time enabled and I don't know a way to impose that is only compile-time enabled; if you want something that works only compile-time, I suppose you have to work with template metaprogramming.

Comment: @max66 Is there a way to force that evaluation of `verify` happens at compile time only so that I can `static_assert` there? is there a way to  analyse characters in string literals with template metaprogramming?

Comment: @DevNull - I don't think so; you can impose a `static_assert()` over `N` because `N` is known compile-time also when the function is executed run-time; but this isn't true for `str`. If you want a compile-time check over `str`, you have to do it (as far I know) via template metaprogramming. I have an half-idea (not really elegant ore useful); if you want I can try to add an example.

Comment: I mean, what language rules make the compiler decides to make it a run-time function instead of compile-time function in this particular case?

Comment: @max66 yes, please.

Comment: @NickyC - as far I know, the compiler is (in this particular case) absolutely free to chose to execute the function run-time or compile-time; the only way I know to force the compile-time execution is impose that the return value (in this case in `void`, so not-applicable) is used in a context where is necessary a value known compile time; that can be initializing a `constexpr` variable or for a template (non type) parameter or for the dimension of an old C-style array.

Comment: @DevNull - answer improved with an example (a silly example, I suppose). Not sure that can be defined "metaprogramming" but I hope can give the idea.